# How to record videos with LG G2 Mini with a lower quality or resolution?

Tags: video, lg, lg-g2, video-recording

Is there a way to force the camera app of the LG G2 Mini to record videos that don't take up a large number of mb for just a few seconds of video? I think it's recording at 1080p, or some other high number. I can't record pass 1 minute it seems, or it'll take up near 1gb of memory (or maybe 500mb, I can't remember).

I looked at the settings of the camera, and apparently there's no other resolutions available, aside from the one that allows for records of .3gp (I think?), but it has a 30 second limit.

Is there an app that allows one to record videos at a lower resolution?

I believe I tried months ago to follow some tutorial where you'll have to edit a system file, but it doesn't work.

So if someone can direct me to a tutorial to deal with this issue or an app it would be greatly appreciated :D I can literally not use my cellphone for video recording for any normal purpose due to the recordings hogging up a huge amount of memory. It's been months since I last attempted to video record anything.

Comment: I used this app (Open Camera) in the past. It sure supports various video recording resolutions and guess what? It's open-source! Head over here --- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera&hl=en

Comment: @MANI What's more interesting is that its size isn't even 1MB yet it supports such varied resolutions *et al*.

Comment: @MANI OMG I LOVE YOU FOR THIS APP I LOVE IT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! >:D< THANKS A LOT!!!! The app even supports changing the destination folder :D I just tried it out :D Now I'm gonna test it's limitations.

Comment: @ValCroft - Welcome! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** This is a partial answer to address the issue using an alternative app.

---

> Is there an app that allows one to record videos at a lower resolution?

In my OnePlus One, I use [Cinema FV-5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flavionet.android.cinema.pro). It shows me following recording resolutions:

- 4096x2160 8.8 MP 4K UHD
- 3840x2160 8.3 MP 16:9 4K UHD
- 1920x1080 2.1 MP 16:9 Full HD
- 1440x1080 1.6 MP 4:3
- 1280x720  0.9 MP 16:9 HD
- 864x480   0.4 MP SD
- 800x480   0.4 MP 15:9 SD
- 720x480   0.3 MP 3:2 NTSC SD
- 640x480   0.3 MP 4:3 SD
- 480x320   0.2 MP 3:2
- 384x288   0.1 MP 4:3
- 352x288   0.1 MP
- 320x240   0.1 MP 4:3
- 176x144   0 MP

[Google Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera) on the other hand allows my device to record at 4K, 1080p and 720p. I'll update my answer if I come to know any other app with varied resolutions capability.

---

**Update 1**: Suggested by @Mani, the app is [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera)(Libre software, free, < 1MB in size). Resolutions are more or less same in variety as Cinema FV-5 has.

Comment: Thanks! Do you use the lite version or the full version? I was wondering what the time limit is for the lite version, and if the full version is worth it? What do you use it for?

Comment: The device isn't actually mine technically but of cousin's and the app was gifted to him by someone I don't know. :) But the installed version is full not lite as far as I know.

Comment: Also, there are many latest (2015) camera apps listed here on Android Authority. Have a look here -- https://web.archive.org/web/20150509155910/http://www.androidauthority.com/best-camera-apps-for-android-188148/